# show icon in actionbar/toolbar with AppCompat-v7 21

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I tried these - but still do not see the icon like before:

```
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

It seems to work when I use custom toolbar - but that would force me to touch all layouts - is there a better way to do so?

Comment: You can add your activity class, where you have added action bar stuff?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

along with

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: Beware that `getSupportActionBar()` could be `null` depending on your activity's style.

Comment: still its not showing icon. i used   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_app_icon);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Label");

Comment: Why Icon shows in middle of the Title bar? I want Icon left side of Title bar. Please help.. Thanks

Comment: How do I find the Icon Image view?

Comment: @Meenaxi you should use setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); That one did the trick for me

Comment: how can i set some action to the home icon

Comment: Note that setting the icon doesn't make it clickable. If you're looking for a clickable icon, you need to use `.setHomeAsUpIndicator` and handle it in your `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Answer (score 32):

> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually
>   distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. The
>   use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged
>   on API 21 devices and newer.

If you disagree you can try with:

To create the toolbar in XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
    android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
```

In your activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Use the [setLogo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setLogo(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) method to set the icon.
[Code source.](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)

Comment: I just want to point out that currently the Play Store `Settings` Activity has the app icon in the action bar. This is still there after the Material update.

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_logo);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //optional
```

as well as:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo); //also displays wide logo
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //optional
```

Comment: there are to many unnecessary methods and not related to icon

Answer (score 17):

simplest thing to do; just add:

```
app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu">
```

to the `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` tag

where `@drawable/ic_action_navigation_menu` is the name of icon

Comment: Works perfectly! This is the correct and simplest way to add the navigation icon in the toolbar. If you want to check for the navigation icon clicks, you can check for `android.R.id.home` ID in your `onOptionsItemSelected(...)`.

Answer (score 12):

A better way for setting multiple options:

`setIcon/setLogo` method will only work if you have set **DisplayOptions** Try this -

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

You can also set options for displaying LOGO(just add constant `ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO`). More information - [displayOptions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayOptions(int,%20int))

Answer (score 6):

Try using:

```
ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
ab.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
ab.setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: sounded promising - but still no Icon :-(

Answer (score 6):

For Actionbar:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
```

For Toolbar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_back);
```

Comment: There is no difference between the 2 code for ActionBar and Toolbar, is this intentional?

Comment: For ActionBar should be:

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_action_back);

Comment: This is actually the way to go. Just using `setIcon` doesn't allow a clickable button, where as `setHomeAsUpIndicator` and handling that in `onOptionsItemSelected` works a treat. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

if you want to set the home or back icon (not logo or static icon) so you can use

```
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator( getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home) );
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, since deploy appearance and behaviour

Comment: only this gave me a normal appearance (size, margins, offset between title and icon), works ok even with vector launcher (`.xml`), like `R.mipmap.ic_launcher` or `R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round`

Comment: and I used this as logo/static icon cause other solutions works ugly

Answer (score 4):

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

**OR** make a XML layout call the `tool_bar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:elevation="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now in you main activity add this line

```
 <include
     android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
     layout="@layout/tool_bar" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you dont want to set your toolbar as action bar using **setSupportActionBar**, you can add a logo next to your navigation icon (if you have a back button for example) like this:

```
toolbar.setLogo();
```

or in xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    ....
    android:logo="@drawable/logo"
    app:logo="@drawable/logo"/>
```

And even if you have a title set on the Toolbar, the the title will still show.

Ex: The green check in the image below is the logo

[image: Toolbar with navigation icon, logo and title]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
...
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

so your icon will be used for Home / back
or

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
...
    ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    actionbar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

for static icon

Answer (score 1):

```
toolbar.setLogo(resize(logo, (int) Float.parseFloat(mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._120sdp) + ""), (int) Float.parseFloat(mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._35sdp) + "")));


public Drawable resize(Drawable image, int width, int height)
{
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) image).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmapResized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmapResized);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.Android you can use these:

```
SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
SupportActionBar.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.ic_launcher);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

using Android.Support.V7.App.AppCompatActivity is required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For me it worked

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin I did the following to just show the icon:

```
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)
supportActionBar?.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_icon_small)
```