# ActionBar Styles being ignored, even the icon is missing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-styles

I have my activity with an action bar which I want to customize, however Android is ignoring all my styles...

This is how it looks now:

[image: Current appearance]

It should look with a blue background instead and the application logo should be there also...

My manifest is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="greensmartcampus.eu.smartcampususerfeedbackapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SmartCampusTheme">
        <!-- Splash screen while connecting to the web-server -->
        <activity
            android:name=".HomeScreen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_home_screen"
            android:parentActivityName=".AbstractPortraitActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="greensmartcampus.eu.smartcampususerfeedbackapp.AbstractPortraitActivity" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- The activity where all actions take place -->
        <activity
            android:name=".ControlActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_control"
            android:parentActivityName=".AbstractPortraitActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="greensmartcampus.eu.smartcampususerfeedbackapp.AbstractPortraitActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My activity xml is the following:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="greensmartcampus.eu.smartcampususerfeedbackapp.ControlActivity" />
```

My styles.xml is the following:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="SmartCampusTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/CustomActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="GenericProgressIndicator" parent="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:indeterminate">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionbar_bg_color</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

I also want to hide those 3 dots in the action bar which open the menu to the settings, which I don't have...

[image: Settings button]

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is related to using the app compatibility library. Try removing the `android:` prefix from your Actionbar styles. See [Styling the Action Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) and [appcompat v21](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/#migration-from-previous-setup).

Answer (score 1):

[AppCompat v21](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) brings the [Material theme](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) to all devices. Two changes with this is the use of the new [color palette](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette) for theming your action bar and activity. In the new system, coloring your action bar is accomplished via a theme such as:

```
<style name="SmartCampusTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionbar_bg_color</item>
</style>
```

In addition, the lack of the app icon is expected. Per the [Toolbar documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html):

> In modern Android UIs developers should lean more on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their application icon. The use of application icon plus title as a standard layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.

The action bar showing a 'Settings' option is part of the initial template - you can delete the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method to remove all items from the options menu.

Comment: But I really need to put the icon there, how can I do it (in the xml)? For example this topic suggest a non-style-xml way of doing it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440279/show-icon-in-actionbar-toolbar-with-appcompat-v7-21?

Comment: About the "onCreateOptionsMenu" method, is there a way to do it in the style.xml (making the method return false or removing it worked as you said)? I really didn't want to mix styles with the code (MVC).

Comment: I am still struggling to find a way to put the icon there, android:background or just background don't work... :(