# Unable to see Logo for Android Actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have been trying to get action bar icon and for some reason it is not coming at all.

Does the size matters when displaying any icon for action bar?

Mine is: 64*64 px.

My Application Manifest looks like this:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:logo="@mipmap/icon_welcome_logo"
        android:icon="@mipmap/icon_welcome_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme"
        >
```

I have even tried to set the same through coding, as well as custom style.

Please advise if I am doing anything wrong??

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public static final String TITLE = "Account Details";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(TITLE);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- general styles for the action bar -->
    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/actionBarBackground</item>
        <item name="android:icon">@mipmap/icon_welcome_logo</item>
        <item name="android:logo">@mipmap/icon_welcome_logo</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">useLogo</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/TitleTextStyle</item>

    </style>

    <!-- action bar title text -->
    <style name="TitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionBarTextColor</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/actionBarTextSize</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "au.com.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.5.1'
}
```

Comment: Try to set only logo in activity. Is it working?

Comment: The problem is in your style.Can u post your style also?

Comment: Post your `build.gradle` and your `styles.xml`

Comment: @JaredBurrows I have just added requested details.

Comment: @codebased Based on your imports and `styles.xml`, are you just now updating your app to use the newer app compat libraries?

Comment: @JaredBurrows It is a new app that  I am building from latest android studio

Comment: I am asking because if you see most of the Material Design apps do not have logos in their ActionBar/Toolbar.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Yes, but I still want this to be available and I am search a way.

Comment: you need to check this tutorial check this tutorial  http://tech-papers.org/android-working-with-action-bar/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your issue is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451433/950427.

**Change:**

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(TITLE);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

**To:**

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(TITLE);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true); // <-- added
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Dependency Updates(Unrelated to question):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' // <-- Updated
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.2' // <-- Updated
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.1' // <-- brings in core
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jarad. I just could not find the reason on why I have to enable ShowHome.

Comment: @codebased Anytime! To shorten your `build.gradle`, I have updated your depdendencies