# App logo on Action Bar in Android Studio is not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-styles

Android Studio is not showing app logo on the Action Bar.

I used following style:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

It is showing logo in my XMl design what While i run it app logo disappear.

Like this is the output of my app

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of material-design is that the logo is not on the actionbar anymore - but you can force to get it back if you want like so:
[show icon in actionbar/toolbar with AppCompat-v7 21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440279/show-icon-in-actionbar-toolbar-with-appcompat-v7-21)

Comment: how to get it back. Thats i am asking?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440279/show-icon-in-actionbar-toolbar-with-appcompat-v7-21

Answer (score 2):

To display the icon on ActionBar you have to add :

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

in onCreate method.