# Android actionbar icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I would like to add an icon in status bar. I tried-

```
getActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.my_icon); //crashes app

getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_statusbar_msg); //not working

<activity android:icon="@drawable/my_icon" /> //also not working

<application android:logo="@drawable/Image"> //still not working
```

Icon is not shown on action bar. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using a support action bar (Toolbar) or standard action bar?

Comment: what is showing when using `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_statusbar_msg);`?

Comment: try this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26440279/show-icon-in-actionbar-toolbar-with-appcompat-v7-21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. **Import v7.widget.Toolbar** and **extends AppCompatActivity**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_statusbar_msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Toolbar instead of actionBar. for this you have to change your style.xml like this:

```
<style name="YourThemeName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and add Toolbar to your activity layout. and in your oncreate method in activity do this:

```
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarId);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("title");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.navigation_right); // change back button image  
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.your_icon);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setIcon. On some images it sets padding or etc. Instead you can extend AppCompatActivity, set the theme to a NoActionBar one, and add a toolbar in your layout file in which you put the image you want. Then you get a reference to the toolbar as @vinoth12594 shows you.
More details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html#add-toolbar).